# Date field from SQL returning date minus 1 with Node/JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a very simple SQL string that brings a Date field from sql:

```
SELECT dbo.table.effDate from table where.....
```

I need to convert that date to a date variable at Node so I can perform a calculation. This date is always the first of a month, so my results at SQL are

```
2023-01-01
2022-05-01
2022-08-01
```

etc.

So, when I try to convert the field to a node date type, in these different ways, I always get the previous date of the one at the field (for the example above)

```
2022-12-31
2022-04-30
2022-07-31
```

Im using:

```
let effDate = moment(response[i].effDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Then

```
let effDate = new Date(response[i].effDate)
```

even this is bringing me a previous date

```
let effDate = response[I].effDate.toString()
```

and this:

```
let effDate = new Date(response[I].effDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US')
```

I could fix this by adding one day to whatever SQL brings me back, but its not the point, I want to do it right.

I also tried using getTimezoneOffset

```
effDate = new Date(response[i].effdate.getTime() - response[i].effdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

But I always get the previous date.

What confuses me is that javascript UTC zones should have nothing to do when it comes to the value returned by SQL:

[image]

Again, I could just add a day but that wont be right, and I would like to know why this is happening (even using toString()).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `Date` treats strings as being the UTC representation of that moment in time (because its the standard format to save a date in a database). Running the following line should give you a better understanding of this:

```js
console.log(new Date('2023-01-01').toString())
```

I get:

```
Sat Dec 31 2022 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Either allow `moment.js` to interpret the string directly, or use the [`.utc()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

```js
// moment from Date object is still UTC, outputs local
console.log('A:', moment(new Date('2023-01-01')).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
// moment parses string assumming local
console.log('B:', moment('2023-01-01').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
// use moment.utc() method to keep output UTC
console.log('C:', moment(new Date('2023-01-01')).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
console.log('D:', moment.utc(new Date('2023-01-01')).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
console.log('E:', moment.utc('2023-01-01').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Arleigh. C above worked perfect. Im still dont have very clear why SQL Server returns something and even when I .toString() the date, takes a day away. But oh well, its working and its working the right way. Thanks again Arleigh.